# mPDF->SetTopMargin causes page break

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf, mpdf

I am automating pdf construction with mPDF (a php library). Several pages of the pdf need to have a top and bottom margins of different sizes.

I am calling `$mpdf -> WriteHTML($html_segment, 2)` for each page.

On the second page my top margin need to be set to 20, so I call `$mpdf -> SetTopMargin(20);`
, however this causes a new (blank) page to be written between (the intended) page 1 and 2!
The adjusted margin appears on page 3 instead.

I have tried switching `$mpdf -> autopagebreak = false`, but that did not seem to do it.

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?